# Помогите в юнити 5 не отображаеться сцена

Tags: unity3d

Было всё нормально но потом что-то пошло не так, и ещё странно что когда ставлю в Canvas Screen Space - Overlay то видно текст хотя есть и другие объекты, но если закрепить камеру то ничего не видно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял дело вот в чем. Если я неправ, то пусть меня поправят.

Когда вы делаете canvas render mode не overlay, то canvas просто находится в мире как плоскость. Из-за этого как и любой другой объект камера может просто его не видеть. Лежит в другой плоскости, повернут ребром и т.д. Когда же ставится render mode overlay, то это говорит что canvas как бы перекрывает другие объекты. Т.е воспринимается системой не как просто объект, а как то, что надо отрисовать на конечное изображение независимо от положения. Таким образом, в данном случае изменение режима на overlay не костыль, а нормальное решение.

Comment: Я добавил скриншот самого Canvas

Comment: @АнатолійБеспалько отредактировал

Comment: Причина была в значениях Clipping Planes

Comment: @АнатолійБеспалько оформите как ответ на счой вопрос. Чтобы другие могли это найти:)